# Why isn't nrpe 'check_procs' finding my Passenger process?

Tags: nagios, nrpe

I'm trying to use `check_procs` from NRPE to find out whether **Passenger** is running on my server. It loads from `httpd` but appears separately.

```
32135 ?        Sl     0:09 Passenger RackApp: /usr/share/puppet/rack/puppetmasterd  
32589 ?        Sl     0:01 Passenger AppPreloader: /usr/share/puppet/rack/puppetmasterd  
32629 ?        Sl     0:05 Passenger RackApp: /usr/share/puppet/rack/puppetmasterd  
32751 ?        Sl     0:05 Passenger RackApp: /usr/share/puppet/rack/puppetmasterd
```

When I try to test it like so:

```
 check_procs -w 2: -c 3: -C Passenger
```

It tells me there are 0 processes found. I see them - how do I get NRPE to count them?

Answer (score 9):

It's likely that the process name is not what you think it is. To find out how `check_process` is looking for your job try this: `check_procs -vv -C Passenger`. You'll see something like this:

```
/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_procs -vv -C Passenger   
CMD: /bin/ps axwo 'stat uid pid ppid vsz rss pcpu comm args'  
PROCS OK: 0 processes with command name 'Passenger'
```

Now take the `ps` command and try it yourself like this:

```
/bin/ps axwo 'stat uid pid ppid vsz rss pcpu comm args' | grep Passenger
```

Notice that there are lots of jobs matching your description... just not named like you thought they would be...

```
S+       0   841 26063 103244   852  0.0 grep            grep Passenger  
Ssl      0 30160  2134 216524  1972  0.0 PassengerWatchd PassengerWatchdog  
Sl       0 30164 30160 1108096 4980  0.2 PassengerHelper PassengerHelperAgent  
Sl      99 30170 30160 219616  4292  0.0 PassengerLoggin PassengerLoggingAgent  
Sl      52 32135     1 217972 113944 1.1 ruby            Passenger RackApp:   /usr/share/puppet/rack/puppetmasterd                
Sl      52 32629     1 235484 131480 1.9 ruby            Passenger RackApp:   /usr/share/puppet/rack/puppetmasterd                
Sl      52 32751     1 218672 114568 1.7 ruby            Passenger RackApp: /usr/share/puppet/rack/puppetmasterd
```

Now change your `check_procs` command to match:

```
/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_procs  -C ruby -a Passenger  
PROCS OK: 3 processes with command name 'ruby', args 'Passenger'
```